# SQL Syntax, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, limit

I have the following syntax, and all runs fine except for "LIMIT". All the results of the database display when only 9 results should. I have the "0, 9" coming from variables so they will change on each paginated link (ex. 0, 9; 10, 18; 19, 27; etc.). I checked and rechecked my syntax and I don't understand why all the results would show. Below is the exact query I'm testing.

Also to note, I'm using XAMPP

```
FROM acb_accfitems WHERE itemtype = 'furniture' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 0, 9
```

Comment: AFAIK `LIMIT 0, 9` should work. Sure your variables have the values you think they do?

Comment: They should since I'm echoing back the query, though there's something going on that isn't showing in the echo since the query works with a static query but not with the variables

Comment: PROBLEM FIXED! For those wondering, the syntax was correct, I had just appended the "LIMIT" clause in the wrong place, so the code without the "LIMIT" was being run. Thank you @Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can do pagination:

```
ORDER BY price LIMIT 10       /* first 10 */
ORDER BY price LIMIT 11, 10   /* second 10 */
ORDER BY price LIMIT 21, 10   /* third 10 */
```

etc.

Comment: Yes - generally speaking, the second parameter in the LIMIT clause denotes the number of records you want - it's not `LIMIT start, end`, it's `LIMIT start, quantity`

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question at all. Which is why `LIMIT 0, 9` is apparently all rows, not just 9.

Comment: I manually removed the variables and placed static values, and just like before echoed out the SQL Query. Both queries when echoed were exactly identical, but the one where I placed static values worked without displaying all the database contents. There's something else going on here that I'll have to look into. Thank you for all your help though, you helped me to narrow down the problem! (here's the queries, they're identical)
FROM acb_accfitems WHERE itemtype = 'furniture' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 0, 9 
FROM acb_accfitems WHERE itemtype = 'furniture' ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 0, 9

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 9

Is what you need.

Comment: Not exactly, I'm making a paginated search so the limit would change each page

Comment: Please put that in the description of your problem, and paste the full query that you're trying to execute, then. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question for clarification